# How to find out why Magento makes an redirect?

Tags: magento, redirect

I'm running a Magento installation with several websites which are more or less configured identically. On one of the websites when I browse to the onepage checkout, which was highly customized, the user gets redirected to the website's homepage, although he should stay on the onepage checkout of course. For every of the other websites this works.

Until the layout rendering part I know that the controller get processed without any errors. And also the all my custom templates which are used in the onepage checkout gets loaded. I added some logging messages so I can see how far the layout got processed.

But just before finishing the render process an internal redirect happens and the homepage gets rendered. At the moment I have no idea how I could find out why or where the redirect happened.

So is there any way to find the source of the redirect?

Comment: When i got this kind of absent things (aways happens with magento) i just get database dump and use search on sql do look for "misterious", in your case the url ;)

Comment: I investigated the network traffic with Chrome and found out that Magento is doing a 301 redirect. I've deactivated caching and rebuild all indexes. But still getting the redirect. One thing to mention, the  only store view of this website was deactivated before. After activating it the problems occur.

Comment: Take a look on Catalog > Url rewrite Management

Comment: I've already deleted the content of the core_url_rewrite table. The weird thing is I can browse to all pages, catalog, products and so on except the onepage checkout

Comment: search for "redirect" in the whole app/code/local folder and check it one by one :)

Comment: Try reverting to default theme. If the problem will go then you have the issue with theme, if not - with extension (assuming your core is not touched).

Comment: On which checkout tab does it do the redirect?

Comment: Ok disabled my theme and module with the customizations and the redirect disappeared. So it's not a core problem.  My onepage checkout is customized, it doesn't have any tabs, everything is on one page.

Comment: Ok I finally found the problem which leads to the error although I still don't understand where the redirect happened. Thanks for your support!